Dialogflow Agent Bot functionality is not working in webpage
I'm trying to add 'Agent' code to a simple HTML webpage. The agent chatbot is being created; however, the chatbot response is not happening. It is taking only the user input & not providing the expected answers from the bot (basically no response). When I'm testing the agent in the console (Dialogflow.cx), it's working fine. Checked Agent Id, all looks ok. What could be the missing link?
